# How to import JavaScript libraries from NPM in an Understrap child theme

Tags: javascript, php, npm, wordpress-theming

I want to utilize the [Chart Js](https://www.chartjs.org/) library in my [Understrap Child Theme](https://docs.understrap.com/#/understrap-child/). I could utilize the CDN script and insert that into my HTML like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

However, this has the drawback of potentially slowing down load times or getting errors if for some reason the CDN is down or no longer exists. So I decided to import it into my `package.json` file like so:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "understrap": "github:understrap/understrap#develop",
    "chart.js": "^4.2.1"
  }
```

*Note: These are not all the `devDependencies` in my `package.json`, this is for example only.*

However, after doing this, I was unsure how to add the `chart.umd.js` file, mentioned in [Chart.js Integration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html), to my theme. I don't want to use `node_modules` in my script `src` reference.

Answer (score 0):

So, after you have added your library to the `package.json` file under `devDependencies` and run `npm install` in your child theme directory you are ready to follow the steps below.

*Note: I will be using Chart.js library for my examples.*

Chart.js suggests using the `chart.umd.js` file for integration, linked in my question. To do this and not use the `node_modules` directory in my script `src`, we need to copy this file and all the dependencies with it. You could do this manually, but there is a script you can take advantage of to do this.

Inside of your child theme, create a new directory in the `src/js` path called `assets`. Inside your `assets` directory create another directory named after your library. Ex. `chart.js`... *Note: this is a directory, not a file.*

After creating your directories, goto `src/build/copy-assets.js` in your child theme. At the end of the file write something like this:

```
copyDir('./node_modules/chart.js/dist', './src/js/assets/chart.js');
```

This will run the `copyDir` function and copy your `dist` directory and write it to `chart.js` inside your child theme's `js/assets' directory.

Next, you will need to run a script that will do the copying. In the same way you run `npm install`, you will need to run the following script:

```
npm run copy-assets
```

Double-check that your files have been copied. If they weren't copied, double-check your paths inside the `copyDir` function call you wrote.

You can now reference your needed javascript files in your Understrap child theme where needed. I used mine like so:

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/src/js/assets/chart.js/chart.umd.js' ) ?>"></script>
```